# Evaluating $ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{1-\tan(\frac{\pi}{4} + x)\cdot\tan(\frac{\pi}{4} + 2x)\cdot\tan(\frac{\pi}{4} - 3x)}{x^3} $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, trigonometry

I tried to calculate this limit but I am stuck, this is for highschoolers level:

$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{1-\tan(\frac{\pi}{4} + x)\cdot\tan(\frac{\pi}{4} + 2x)\cdot\tan(\frac{\pi}{4} - 3x)}{x^3} $$

I tried l'hopital's rule but it didn't work, it became too complicated, and I tried $ \tan(A+B)=\frac{\tan(A)+\tan(B)}{1–\tan(A)\tan(B)} $
but also didn't work, it also became too complicated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a sketch of a solution based on Taylor expansion. Possibly not the fastest way to go about this but usually a safe technique. I leave all computations for you (otherwise this will give an unnecessary long posting).

First work with the Taylor expansion of the function $g(x)=\tan(\frac{\pi}{4}+x)$ around $x=0$. Keep terms up tp order $3$ to be able to control the denominator $x^3$ in your expression.

$$\tan(\frac{\pi}{4}+x)=1+2x+2x^2+\frac{8}{3}x^3+o(x^3)\quad\text{as}\quad{x\rightarrow0}
$$

The algebraic part is not so bad considering that one only needs to
keep track of terms of order up to 3 (i.e. powers $x^n$, with $0\leq n\leq 3$) and absorb higher powers into the term $o(x^3)$.

\begin{align}
G(x)&=1-\tan(\frac{\pi}{4} + x)\cdot\tan(\frac{\pi}{4} + 2x)\cdot\tan(\frac{\pi}{4} - 3x)\\
&=-\big(2x+2x^2+\frac{8}{3}x^3+o(x^3)\big)\big(4x+8x^2+\frac{64}{3}x^3 +o(x^3)\big)\big(-6x+18x^2-72x^3+o(x^3))\big)-\\
&\qquad\big(2x+2x^2+\frac{8}{3}x^3+o(x^3)\big)\big(4x+8x^2+\frac{64}{3}x^3 +o(x^3)\big)-\\
&\qquad\big(2x+2x^2+\frac{8}{3}x^3+o(x^3)\big)\big(-6x+18x^2-72x^3+o(x^3)\big)-\\
&\qquad \big(4x+8x^2+\frac{64}{3}x^3 +o(x^3)\big)\big(-6x+18x^2-72x^3+o(x^3)\big)+\\
&\qquad\qquad -2x-2x^2-\frac{8}{3}x^3-4x-8x^2-\frac{64}{3}x^3+6x-18x^2 +72x^3+o(x^3)\\
&=24x^3+ o(x^3)
\end{align}

The rest is straight forward
$$\frac{1-\tan(\frac{\pi}{4} + x)\cdot\tan(\frac{\pi}{4} + 2x)\cdot\tan(\frac{\pi}{4} - 3x)}{x^3}=24(1+o(1))\xrightarrow{x\rightarrow0}24
$$

Answer (score 3):

The approach using the formula $$\tan(a+b) =\frac{\tan a+\tan b} {1-\tan a\tan b} $$ works fine.

Using the formula and noting that $\tan (\pi/4)=1$ we can transform the expression under limit into $$\frac{(1-\tan x) (1-\tan 2x)(1+\tan 3x)-(1+\tan x) (1+\tan 2x)(1-\tan 3x)} {x^3(1-\tan x) (1-\tan 2x)(1+\tan 3x)} $$ Since the last three factors in denominator tend to $1$ the limit of above fraction is equal to the limit of $$\frac{2\tan x\tan 2x\tan 3x-2(\tan x+\tan 2x-\tan 3x)} {x^3} $$ Using the fact that $$\tan 3x=\frac{\tan x+\tan 2x}{1-\tan x\tan 2x}$$ we can rewrite the above expression as $$\frac{2\tan x\tan 2x\tan 3x-2((1-\tan x\tan 2x)\tan 3x-\tan 3x)}{x^3}$$ or $$\frac{4\tan x\tan 2x\tan 3x}{x^3}$$ And now the limit is evaluated as $24$ by writing the above expression as $$4\cdot\frac{\tan x} {x} \cdot 2\cdot \frac{\tan 2x}{2x}\cdot 3\cdot\frac{\tan 3x}{3x}$$

Answer (score 2):

Using the $\tan(A+B)$ identity is not a bad way to strip away the "obviously" finite parts of the limand. We have

$$\tan\left(\frac\pi4\pm nx\right) = \frac{1 \pm \tan(nx)}{1 \mp \tan(nx)},$$

so that the limit, denoted $L$, can be rewritten as

$$\begin{align*}
L &= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-\tan(\frac{\pi}{4} + x)\cdot\tan(\frac{\pi}{4} + 2x)\cdot\tan(\frac{\pi}{4} - 3x)}{x^3} \\
&= 2 \lim_{x \to0} \frac{\color{blue}{\tan x\tan(2x)\tan(3x)} - \tan x - \tan (2x) + \tan(3x)}{\color{blue}{x^3} \color{red}{(1-\tan x) (1 - \tan(2x)) (1+\tan(3x))}}
\end{align*}$$

Apply the sum and product rule for limits. As $x\to0$, each of the terms in red will converge to $1$ so we can effectively omit them. The terms in blue can be addressed by recalling $\frac{\tan x}{x}\to1$ as $x\to0$. This leaves us with

$$L = 12 - 2 \lim_{x \to0} \frac{\tan x + \tan (2x) - \tan(3x)}{x^3}$$

Taylor series would make short work of this last limit, but that's not entirely necessary. Express $\tan(nx)$ in terms of $\tan x$:

$$\begin{align*}
\tan(2x) &= \frac{2\tan x}{1-\tan^2x} \\
\tan(3x) &= \frac{3\tan x-\tan^3x}{1-3\tan^2x}
\end{align*}$$

$$\implies L = 12 - 2 \lim_{x \to0} \color{green}{\frac{\tan x}x} \cdot \frac{1 + \frac2{1-\tan^2x} - \frac{3-\tan^2x}{1-3\tan^2x}}{x^2}$$

As in the "blue" step, the green terms will converge to $1$. Finally, combining the remaining fractions in the numerator will reveal a common factor of $\tan^2x$ that we can ignore à la the "green" step.

$$L = 12 - 4 \lim_{x\to0} \color{green}{\frac{\tan^2x}{x^2}} \cdot \frac{\tan^2x-3}{\left(1-\tan^2x\right) \left(1-3\tan^2x\right)} = 12 - 4 \cdot 1 \cdot (-3) = \boxed{24}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $a=\tan x,b=\tan2x,c=\tan3x$

Using $\tan(p+q)$ formula,

$$F=1-\dfrac{(1+a)(1+b)(1-c)}{(1-a)(1-b)(1+c)}$$

On simplification,

$$\dfrac F2=\dfrac{abc-(a+b-c)}{(1-a)(1-b)(1+c)} $$

Again, $\tan(2x+x)=\dfrac{\tan2x+\tan x}{1-\tan2x\tan x}$

$\implies\tan x+\tan2x-\tan3x=-abc$

So, $\dfrac F2=\dfrac{2abc}{(1-a)(1-b)(1+c)}$

Finally $\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{\tan mh}h=m$ for finite $m$ $\implies\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{abc}{x^3}=1\cdot2\cdot3$